# Error establishing database connection on Cloudflare

Tags: database, dns, cloudflare

I have an Asp.Net website with SSL.
My website was working before but
I get `Error establishing database connection` error after I have used Cloudflare DNS adresses.

I have searched on Cloudflare and found [this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169836-Why-am-I-getting-an-error-saying-Error-establishing-database-connection-) info
but my hosting provider wants me to ask to Cloudflare.

How can I add my DB adress to Cloudflare ?

Comment: If you revert DNS to old setting, does everything work fine? How does your app connect to database, using name or IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it resolved :

I used the database `IP address` on Web.config 
rather than using my `domain's address`.